# Borland C++ v3.0 Graphics issue

Tags: c++, turbo-c++, bgi, borland-c++

My turbo c++ cannot support graphics programs and it tells "bgi error : Graphics not initialized ". What do I do?
I'm running on:
OS: Windows 8 Pro
GPU: Zotac GTX550ti

Comment: I would recommend not using Turbo.

Comment: Alternatively, run it in a VM which supports the environment. TBH, use a newer compiler and graphics toolkit. Legacy environment support is not really a StackOverflow issue.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legacy support for very old tools and hardware.

Comment: Is there anywhere in the rules written about that old tools/hardware questions are undesired? From my pov this is still a real-life problem and valid question (not for many though).

Answer (score 1):

The Borland Graphics Interface has drivers for commonly used video cards that have gone long ago. Since GBI does not support your hardware you two choices:

- buy older hardware (I dont' count this, therefore "2 choices".)
- change the tool
- use a virtualisation (virtual VM)

There are more usable tools like Windows Forms for current hardware. You should consider to drop a tool where the vendor can't be found anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at BGI emulations for Windows, like this:
http://bgi-for-windows.apponic.com/
or
http://www.cs.colorado.edu/~main/bgi/doc/

But I recommend to look for a modern approach for using graphics under Window.